# Does MySQL packet size cause slowdown?

Tags: mysql

I have written a program which uses a [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) database, and transaction between the database server (a very powerful one) and the client is happening over a [ADSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_digital_subscriber_line) connection (1 Mbit/s).

But I have a very very slow connection between each client and the server. Only approximately 3-4 KB/s data is send through the server. Neither the server nor the clients use the Internet for other purposes, just my program uses the Internet.

I can't figure out why? Is the reason MySQL server packet size?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind to explain what the reason for your slowdown actually was?

Comment: @Daniel Schneller 
uh-oh sorry. I use "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM" large InnoDB tables and it causes slowdown. I've changed my programming ideas and now MySQL is very fast than ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [mytop](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/mysql/mytop/) to identify the server low performance cause.
Another one: you may be using SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ..  for large InnoDB tables which causes a table scan.

And can you test for some other services whether the exchange data rate between the machines is OK? Even if the even if the output bandwidth is lower for ADSL users 3-4 kB might not be the reason of low performance.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to debug both connections.

What is your upload speed if you upload a file with [WinSCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP) ot equivalent to the MySQL server? It should be near 90 KB/s with ADSL 1 Mbit/s.

Comment: I checked but server has a good upload speed which is over 80kb/s.
Any different ideas?

Comment: test with SQLyog or similar GUI
try SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; to see if theres any other queries
check config with SHOW VARIABLES;

max_allowed_packet doesnt affect the 'bandwidth'

Answer (score 1):

The effective transfer rate is often heavily limited by the number of roundtrips between client and server. Without seeing your code it is sort of difficult to tell, but you should check the number of requests happening.
If you have a single request that results in many records being returned, you should see a better usage of bandwidth than with a higher number of requests which only deliver a few rows each.

In the latter case the actual result transfer is probably quite fast, but the latencies involved in the "control communications" (i. e. the statements themselves, login requests etc.)  will add up, effectively lowering overall throughput.

As for the packet size: When it is very small, there is more overhead in the communications, increasing the aforementioned effect. The server's default `max_allowed_packet` size if 1MB if memory serves, but that should be fine with your connection.